# How to properly define a fatal_esyscmd in gnu m4

Tags: m4

I'd like a simple wrapper around esyscmd that aborts on failure.
My current attempt is:

```
$ cat fatal-syscmd 
define(`fatal_esyscmd', `esyscmd( `$1' )`'dnl
ifelse(sysval,`0',`',`errprint(`error: $1 failed
')m4exit(1)')')dnl
dnl
dnl
fatal_esyscmd(`printf "%s" foo')
here
false: fatal_esyscmd(`false')
after false
$ m4 fatal-syscmd 
foo
here
false: error: false failed
```

This "seems to" work, but I have absolutely zero confidence in its robustness.  What is the correct way to quote this?